# Google Analytics: chart and table show different number of users

Tags: charts, google-analytics, datatables, analytics

In both iOS and Android app Google Analytics show quite different numbers of unique users on chart and in the table:

[image: [Report: chart and table with different numbers of users]

The problem is the same even for different time intervals. A strange thing is that chart shows **much more** users than the table: an opposite case is not a problem, just several users can be mentioned in different events (or time interval, like [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23585678/9327488)). But on the chart GA counts more people, than the sum of active users based on the events.

Is it a bug? Or GA just counts active users using some other stuff, not the events?

Here is my report settings:

[image: Report settings]

Comment: What information do you get, when you move your mouse over the yellow shield, next to the report title? It is usually related to sampling or chart specific notifications. You'll likely to see this, which is related to your question: The table rows have been filtered to include only data for "Event Category". The graph and table headers include totals for all data.

Comment: @kgrg you are right! But I cannot understand what does it mean `to include only data for Event Category`... That not all events have categories?

Comment: I think that means, not all users have events. I'm not sure, why the chart is not filtered, I can't find related documentation.

Comment: @kgrg thank you anyway! Probably by "data" they mean not only events, because all the events have categories. So, the question is still open.